# delete parts of a character vector

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector which looks like this

```
"9/14/2007,,,,88.22"  "9/21/2007,,,,92.53"  "9/28/2007,,,,92" "10/5/2007,,,,92.85"
```

Now i need to remove all the elements before the 4 commas. So at the end it should look like this

```
"88.22"   "92.53"   "92"      "92.85"
```

I have tried the following code

```
gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x)
```

where x is my character vector but this keeps the integers before the commas (which are dates).

```
"914200788.22"   "921200792.53"   "928200792"      "105200792.85"
```

Also the number of elements to remove isnt always the same but the last one to remove is always the last comma. Maybe this will help for the solution.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote arrow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex just removes non-number characters. Try substituting everything before and including the four commas:

```
> vec = c("9/14/2007,,,,88.22",   "9/21/2007,,,,92.53",   "9/28/2007,,,,92",      "10/5/2007,,,,92.85")
> sub(".*,,,,", "", vec)
[1] "88.22" "92.53" "92"    "92.85"
```

Comment: or `sub("\\d\\d?/\\d\\d?/\\d{4},,,,", "", vec)` if you want to make sure to match the dates...

Comment: Thank you very much. It works just the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

With **`stringr` `str_extract`**:

```
string = c("9/14/2007,,,,88.22",  "9/21/2007,,,,92.53",  "9/28/2007,,,,92", "10/5/2007,,,,92.85")

library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "\\d+[.]?\\d+$")
```

Or

```
str_extract(string, "(?<=,{4}).*")
```

**Base R** equivalent:

```
unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr("\\d+[.]?\\d+$", string)))

unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=,{4}).*", string, perl = TRUE)))

sapply(str_split(string, ",,,,"), `[`, 2)
```

**Notes:**

1. `$` matches the end of string
2. `(?<=,{4})` is a positive lookbehind which checks whether `.*` is *after* 4 commas. This requires perl regex, which is why `perl = TRUE` is required for the second Base R example.

Answer (score 0):

Read the vector as a csv, then refer to the column.  To get the last one without knowing how many original columns there are, we can reverse it and take the first.

```
rev(read.table(text = x, sep = ","))[[1]]
# [1] 88.22 92.53 92.00 92.85
```

Data:

```
x <- scan(text='"9/14/2007,,,,88.22"  "9/21/2007,,,,92.53"  "9/28/2007,,,,92" "10/5/2007,,,,92.85"', what="")
```